# How to call angular typescript function from code behind in asp.net

Tags: .net, angular

Is there any way to call angular typescript function from c# code in asp.net?

I have an angular and .net application and i want to call angular type script
function from code behind. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why you want to call typescript function in code behind?

Comment: I have a scenario where i have to call typescript function in code behind. Is there any way?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense.  Angular apps are client side, they request data from the server via ajax (HTTP) requests and update the browser.  They don't communicate with the server in any way which would allow the server to re-render the page.  If your server needs to communicate with a running app, it either needs to send the data in the HTTP response when the browser requests it, or you need to use some sort of signaling app like SignalR or Socket.io

Comment: And for the record, when someone asks for clarification, i.e. "Why you want to call typescript function in code behind?", " 
I have a scenario where i have to call typescript function` isn't clarification, it's re-stating the same question.  That response doesn't help anyone understand what you are *actually trying to accomplish*.  Instead, it only helps confirm that this is an XY Problem.  You have some Unknown problem, and you think calling the function from the server is the solution, but it can't be, because that's not how Angular applications work.